# Run container non-interactively and echo environment variable

Tags: bash, docker

I'm writing literate style documentation which shows how to set up a Debian-based Docker container.  Debian links `/bin/sh` to the `dash` shell.  I want to show that specifying "bash" in CMD makes the argument passed to the container use `bash` instead of `dash` when run.  To do this, I thought echoing `$BASH_VERSION` would work.  Unfortunately, the output is literally "$BASH_VERSION".

```
C:\Users\me>docker run --rm a6916e41aa87 echo "$BASH_VERSION"
$BASH_VERSION
```

When I run the container interactively, the `BASH_VERSION` is defined as expected:

```
C:\Users\me>docker run --rm -it a6916e41aa87
root@c4f60657c031:/# echo "$BASH_VERSION"
5.2.15(1)-release
```

My container looks like:

```
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED       CREATED BY                                                                                          SIZE      COMMENT
sha256:a6916e41aa871b09260f8949fe3c34570719f1c92ffe87d515b7eb702ebaebb1   2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                                                                     0B
<missing>                                                                 2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:077a3156bd8271f26498ae6ac3800e68a42b9277581bc81eea31fec1a123dca5 in /    117MB
```

The first layer is a minimal Debian install<sup>1</sup> and the second layer sets the run command to "bash".

I can check the environment variables, apparently, using `docker inspect`:

```
C:\Users\me>docker inspect a6916e41aa87 --format "{{.Config.Env}}"
[PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin]
```

So, maybe `BASH_VERSION` isn't defined?  However, I can't even echo `PATH`:

```
C:\Users\me>docker run --rm a6916e41aa87 echo "$PATH"
$PATH
```

Meanwhile, I am able to echo in general:

```
C:\Users\me>docker run --rm -it a6916e41aa87 echo "hello world"
hello world
```

Why am I unable to non-interactively echo environment variables?

How can I demonstrate non-interactively that the container runs commands using `bash` and not `dash`?

<sup>1</sup> https://github.com/debuerreotype/debian-debuerreotype/tree/master

Comment: May I ask why the question was closed and how the supposed "duplicate" relates to my question?  I spent 40 minutes writing my question and it's insanely disrespectful to simply close it immediately without any explanation.  As far as I understand bash, as well as the linked "duplicate", single quotes don't expand variables whereas double quotes do.  My question uses double quotes for this reason.  So, the variable should expand and hence my question.  I've tried every combination of single and double quotes in every position possible in my run command.  There is no difference of behaviour.

Comment: I have a feeling this is more to do with your windows terminal swapping ' and " in the background. your code looks correct

Comment: I would also always wrap my command in single quotes to ensure "$PATH" doesn't get expanded until its within the containers shell. eg. `docker run --rm ubuntu:18.04 bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'` OR `docker run --rm ubuntu:18.04 dash -c 'echo "$PATH"'`

Comment: `root@host:~# docker run --rm ubuntu:18.04 bash -c 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"'
4.4.20(1)-release` VS `root@host:~# docker run --rm ubuntu:18.04 echo "$BASH_VERSION"
5.1.16(1)-release`